# XAML template Datatrigger foreground not changing

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to style a button that will have the  fill color change when the foreground color is changed. However, the dataTrigger I'm using is not going through. After hours of search, I've understand that the local color override the style but I can't figure out how to make this work.

I'm trying to pass the color through Foreground by binding the template in the style template and then using a dataTrigger on the button itself to change it based on a boolean binding.

Here's the code:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" Style="{DynamicResource PowerButton}" >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CR_mainKillSwitch, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CR_mainKillSwitch, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button>
```

The Style within the ressources:

```
<Style x:Key="PowerButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#cccccc" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#ddd" Offset="0.9"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#eee" Offset="0.6"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#eee" Offset="0"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">                        
                <Grid Width="100"  Height="100">
                    <Ellipse Fill="#555">
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Ellipse Width="98" Height="98" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    <Path Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="#555" Width="40" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                        <Path.Data>
                            F1 M 36.4167,36.4167L 36.4167,17.4167L 41.1667,17.4167L 41.1667,36.4167L 36.4167,36.4167 Z M 57,39.5833C 57,50.0767 48.4934,58.5833 38,58.5833C 27.5066,58.5833 19,50.0767 19,39.5833C 19,30.7301 25.0552,23.2911 33.25,21.1819L 33.25,27.8374C 28.6079,29.7165 25.3333,34.2675 25.3333,39.5833C 25.3333,46.5789 31.0044,52.25 38,52.25C 44.9956,52.25 50.6667,46.5789 50.6667,39.5833C 50.6667,34.8949 48.1194,30.8014 44.3333,28.6113L 44.3333,21.6645C 51.7129,24.2728 57,31.3106 57,39.5833 Z
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never applied the style with the triggers to the button. You made it the button's content instead, but the template in the style you *do* apply ignores the button's content completely, so it just kind of vanishes.

Your way isn't the best way to do this (see below for an approach I prefer), but to do what you wanted, what you want to do is set the button's style to a new style that is *based on* `PowerButton`, and adds the triggers to it.

And you want to make sure `CR_mainKillSwitch` is actually a property of the button's DataContext, and you might as well get rid of the no-op properties in the bindings.

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" >
    <!-- 
    This Button.Style element is how you set the Style property of Button with XML elements
    instead of with an attribute. 
    -->
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource PowerButton}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CR_mainKillSwitch}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CR_mainKillSwitch}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

---

**But this is a much better way to do it:**

```
<Style x:Key="PowerButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#cccccc" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#ddd" Offset="0.9"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#eee" Offset="0.6"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#eee" Offset="0"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid Width="100"  Height="100">
                    <Ellipse Fill="#555">
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Ellipse Width="98" Height="98" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    <Path Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="#555" Width="40" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                        <Path.Data>
                            F1 M 36.4167,36.4167L 36.4167,17.4167L 41.1667,17.4167L 41.1667,36.4167L 36.4167,36.4167 Z M 57,39.5833C 57,50.0767 48.4934,58.5833 38,58.5833C 27.5066,58.5833 19,50.0767 19,39.5833C 19,30.7301 25.0552,23.2911 33.25,21.1819L 33.25,27.8374C 28.6079,29.7165 25.3333,34.2675 25.3333,39.5833C 25.3333,46.5789 31.0044,52.25 38,52.25C 44.9956,52.25 50.6667,46.5789 50.6667,39.5833C 50.6667,34.8949 48.1194,30.8014 44.3333,28.6113L 44.3333,21.6645C 51.7129,24.2728 57,31.3106 57,39.5833 Z
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!-- 
                    Let it be the default foreground for null, if that ever happens. 
                    ToggleButton.IsChecked is bool?, three-state. 
                    -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage. You may not need to bother with the Click event.

```
<ToggleButton 
    Click="Button_Click" 
    Style="{DynamicResource PowerButton}"
    IsChecked="{Binding CR_mainKillSwitch}"
    />
```

Comment: Thank you. I like your way a lot more than was I was trying to achieve. I love this language. i find it so powerful when you know what you're doing.

Comment: Indeed. I never get tired of it.